# Break unordered list items across columns with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to break list items inside an unordered list with flexbox? I want to create a 3-column drop-down menu.

For example, my html is:

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="./?>Navigation link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="./?>Navigation link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="./?>Navigation link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="./?>Navigation link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="./?>Navigation link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't want it to display like this:

```
Navigation link 1 | Navigation link 2
Navigation link 3 | Navigation link 4
Navigation link 5 |
```

I want it to display like this:

```
Navigation link 1 | Navigation Link 5
Navigation link 2 |
Navigation link 3 |
Navigation link 4 |
```

I tried using flexbox and I applied these properties but I couldn't find a way to break the list items into more than 1 column:

```
#nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

This means that flex items are forced to stay in a single line.

To create a multiline flex container you can override this setting with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

It's also important to define a height for the container. Otherwise, additional flex items may simply expand the container with no need to wrap.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: If setting the height is a deal breaker for the use case you can use CSS3 text columns. See https://css-tricks.com/arranging-elements-top-bottom-instead-left-right-float/#aa-text-columns